# Getting FormatException over and over again

Tags: c#, formatexception

I'm trying to calculate the area of different objects. All these object have their own `WinForm.` I want to do the calculations in a `CalculationBase` class, but when I try to do that, I keep getting a message over a `FormatException.` Here's my code:

In my `Program.cs` I create a reference to the form I want to calculate in.

```
static class Program
    {
        public static frmRectangle formRect;
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            formRect = new frmRectangle();

            Application.Run(new frmMain());
        }
    }
```

In the `CalculationBase` class I declared the variables as `double breadth, height;` And I put in the following code to do the calculation:

```
private void Calculations()
        {
            FormCheck();
            if (rect)
            {

                Debug.WriteLine("Rectangular is open");

                // Area
                Program.formRect.txtFormArea.Text = string.Format("A = {0} * {1}", b, h);
                if (millimeters)
                    i = (int)Math.Pow(10, 2);
                else if (centimeters)
                    i = (int)Math.Pow(10, 4);

                areaPrimair = Math.Round((b * h), 4);
                areaSecundair = Math.Round((areaPrimair / i), 4);

                Program.formRect.txtAreaPrimair.Text = areaPrimair.ToString();
                Program.formRect.txtAreaSecundair.Text = areaSecundair.ToString();
            }
        }
```

This function is called in a ClickEvent:

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                try
                {
                    breadth = double.Parse(Program.formRect.txtBreadthInput.Text);
                    height = double.Parse(Program.formRect.txtHeightInput.Text);

                    Calculations();
                }
                catch(FormatException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Some values are invalid. Please check your input.", "Invalid value");
                }
            }
        }
```

As said before, my program keeps on showing the message for the FormatException.

Comment: And affter debugging, where did you find the exception to occur?

Comment: If you pass b and h to Calculations, why do you parse it again there? In short: `Program.formRect.txtBreadthInput.Text` and/or `Program.formRect.txtHeightInput.Text` do not represent `doubles` in a valid format. Maybe your culture is `en-us` but a user entered `1.000,50` which would be valid f.e. in germany.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on Calculations line in event, then read breadth and height values.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Sorry about that double parsing, I just updated the code as it is now.

Comment: @astander the exception occurs when I give some input values and click the calculate button

Comment: Do you know at which line the error occurs? And as @zgnilec specified, what are the actual string values of b and h?

Comment: What are the string values of breadth and height?

Comment: @zgnilec Using a breakpoint at the try-block, the string values of b and h are "", after giving input...

Comment: @FJPoort: Now i don't understand why you're using fields when you're passing them as arguments anyway. Either remove the fields or remove the method parameters. The way you do is just error-prone.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I removed the method parameters, still same result

Comment: @FJPoort: The problem is certainly in `double.Parse(Program.formRect.txtBreadthInput.Text);` or next line. So you should show us what culture you're using and what the user entered(the two string values `txtBreadthInput.Text` and `txtHeightInput.Text`). You should also [**learn how to use the debugger**](http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging) ;)

Comment: You can also use the [`Double.TryParse` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: @TimSchmelter My regional settings are English(us) if you mean that by culture. The input I give in the textboxes are for example 5 and 18

Comment: When I use Debug.Writeline(Program.formRect.txtBreadthInput.Text) it returns a empty string

Comment: WHat kind of object is txtBreadthInput? Maybe you accessing Text property which may be "", but this objects contains string[] Lines or something.

Comment: @zgnilec Sorry, I don't understand what you mean here. What should I look for?

Comment: txtBreadthInput : what is the type of this object?

Comment: @zgnilec txtBreadthInput is a textbox where the user gives input

Comment: OK, try add a button to a form which will show user entered values: MessageBox.Show (txtHeightInput.Text);

Comment: @zgnilec Like I said above, When I use Debug.Writeline(Program.formRect.txtBreadthInput.Text) it returns a empty string. Messagebox is empty as well. I did type '5' in the textbox, hit the button to launch messagebox, but it was empty.

Comment: Hmmm without full source code I can do nothing. Maybe investigate Lines property on your text box.

Comment: @zgnilec Lines property is String[] Array

Comment: I know, but that property contains text which you entered in text box.

Comment: @zgnilec When I access a label through the same way and use MessageBox.Show(Program.frmRect.label1.Text); it shows the text correct. Now I want to do this with textbox

Comment: Something is wrong with your code. Maybe Add Trace Point to textBox.Text.

Comment: @TimSchmelter when I want to use the Double.TryParse() method, I'm getting an error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'double'. I'm confused, cause, where the heck does that 'bool'come from? I used: breadth = double.TryParse(Program.formRect.txtBreadthInput.Text, out breadth);

Comment: [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) returns a `bool` which indicates if it was converted successfully. So you can write: `if(double.TryParse(Program.formRect.txtBreadthInput.Text, out breadth));
//....`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Now I did:
if (double.TryParse(Program.formRect.txtBreadthInput.Text, out breadth)) MessageBox.Show(Program.formRect.txtBreadthInput.Text);
But the messagebox never appears.

Answer (score 1):

When you a pass a empty string or a non numeric string to  `Double.Parse("")`,you get a formatexception.
Make sure you are entering a double string,before you hit the button

Comment: Input is always a double, but still getting the formatexception. As said, when I use a breakpoint on the try-block and read the value for the textboxes it sais it's an empty string...

Comment: check if your textfield names in ur code and the winforms project match

Comment: you can comment these lines off b = breadth;h = height; from ur calc method